# Hide rooting to an application

Tags: root-access

I'm currently using a custom Android 5.0 ROM on a Sony Z1c and thoroughly enjoying the freedom.

Looking forward to a point very soon when I can install MultiROM and have the Ubuntu Touch installed aswell.... having OS specific for applications makes good sense.

However.... one thing I need someone clever to help me with is to write me some code I can install to Android that will allow me to hide the fact that I have root access so i can continue to benefit from using the incredibly convenient Barclays Banking app. I've unfortunately discovered that it is patched to check for root access and tells me it is 'unable' to work on rooted devices.

My current ROM is CyanogenMod 12 which has the ability to 'disable' root access, but even so, the banking app can tell that my phone has the access to root.

Hoping someone clever would appreciate the challenge of working out how to 'cloak' my root access ability and allow me to get the app working again on my phone and save me having to go the very long way around via browser login to my online bank account. I think Barclays is being unduly 'Paranoid Android'.... :-)

Whatever you need I can send..... having ES File Explorer installed allows me to pluck anything from the system

Answer (score 2):

See if this app [RootCloack](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-rootcloak-completely-hide-root-t2574647) can help you...it can hide root for a specific app you can choose by hiding binaries apks and other ways...it should work

Comment: This will not work.  RootCloak requires Cydia Substrate and Cydia Substrate does not run beyond Android 4.3.  The user is on Android 5.